# R read.csv Importing Column Names Incorrectly

Tags: r, dataframe, read.csv

I have a csv that I would like to import into R as a data.frame. This csv has headers such as `USD.ZeroCouponBondPrice(1m)` and `USD-EQ-SP500` that I can't change. When I try to import it into R, however, R's `read.csv` function overwrites the characters `()-` as `.` Although I wasn't able to find a way to fix this in the function [documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html), this line of code worked:

```
colnames(df)<-c('USD.ZeroCouponBondPrice(1m)', 'USD-EQ-SP500')
```

so those characters are legal in `data.frame` column names. Overwriting all of the column names is annoying and fragile as there are over 20 of them and it is not unthinkable for them to change. Is there a way to prevent `read.csv` from replacing those characters, or an alternative function to use?

Comment: I'm not sure how, but possible you could make some hack using `Tibbles`. With `Tibbles` you can [use _crazy name_](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tibble/vignettes/tibble.html) for the names of variables.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you set the argument

```
check.names = FALSE
```

in read.csv, then R will not override the names. But these names are not valid in R and they'll have to be handled differently than valid names.

Comment: One example of "handled differently" is if you are using `$` notation to reference a variable you will need backticks around the variable name, e.g. `df$\`USD.ZeroCouponBondPrice(1m)\``.

Answer (score -2):

Illustrating a possible `Tibbles` solution utilizing [Kelli-Jean's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46814994/1305688) on how to use `check.names = FALSE`

```
# install.packages(c("tidyverse"), dependencies = TRUE)
library(tibble)
dta <- url("http://s3.amazonaws.com/csvpastebin/uploads/a4c665743904ea8f18dd1f31edcbae04/crazy_names.csv")
TBdta <- as_tibble(read.csv(dta, check.names = FALSE)) 
TBdta
#> # A tibble: 6 x 3
#>   USD.ZeroCouponBondPrice(1m) USD-EQ-SP500 crazy name
#>                        <fctr>        <dbl>      <int>
#> 1                           A         10.0         12
#> 2                           A         11.0         14
#> 3                           B          5.0          8
#> 4                           B          6.0         10
#> 5                           A         10.5         13
#> 6                           B          7.0         11
```

Be sure to read [this introduction to `Tibbles`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tibble/vignettes/tibble.html) as they do behave somewhat different from regular data frames.

In case someone need to use `https`

```
temporaryFile <- tempfile()
download.file("https://s3.amazonaws.com/csvpastebin/uploads/a4c665743904ea8f18dd1f31edcbae04/crazy_names.csv", destfile = temporaryFile, method="curl")
TBdta2 <- as_tibble(read.csv(temporaryFile, check.names = F))
```

Comment: You can use invalid names for variables in a native data frame, as the result of `read.csv(dta, check.names = FALSE)` shows. The only difference I see with tibbles is it doesn't automatically convert names when you use the `tibble()` function to create one. I don't see any added benefit to wrapping `as_tibble()` around `read.csv()`, at least as far as the OP's question goes.

Comment: @BrianStamper I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: I accepted @Kelli-Jean's answer because it was easier to implement as a solution, but I found this answer helpful as a legitimate alternative. I didn't specify that I wanted an answer that uses only R's base packages, so I don't think this answer deserves the down vote (not sure if it was you).